# Replace tabs in a file with semi-colons using Windows batch script

Tags: batch-file

I want to replace all the TAB characters with semi-colons in my data file.How do I do that?

I want to be able to do that using Windows (MS-DOS) batch script.

Answer (score 2):

You could use this [BatchSubstitute](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=5713#p5713) function.

Or a bit simpler for your special case this replaces `TAB` with `;`

```
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('"findstr /n ^^ myFile.txt"') do (
   set "line=%%A"
   setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

   set "line=!line:*:=!"
   if defined line (
      set "line=!line:  =;!"
      (echo(!line!)
   ) ELSE echo(
   endlocal
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Autohotkeys version of replacing one value with another.

```
#Env
SendMode Input

SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%
FileSelectFile, filname,3,%A_ScriptDir%\*.csv, comma-separated values (*.csv)  
FileRead, content, %filname%

Outputvar := regexreplace(content,";",",") ;Thisone replaces ; with ,  
;Outputvar := regexreplace(content,"\x20{3,}",",") ;Thisone replaces 3 spaces or more with ,  
FileDelete %filname%  
FileAppend, %Outputvar%, %filname%
```

Answer (score 0):

Install `sed` from **UnxUtils** *Native Win32 ports of some GNU utilities*
http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/

and then try this

```
sed "s/\t/;/g" input.txt >output.txt
```