# Safe way to concatenate DOS variables to avoid unseen tab characters causing a double execution of a DEL command?

Tags: batch-file, dos

I have a batch file:
C:\zzzztemp\zzzBUG_TEST.cmd

```
set backup_folder=.\BUG_TEST
echo %backup_folder%\*.*
del %backup_folder%\*.*
pause
```

...whose output is:

```
C:\zzzztemp>set backup_folder=.\BUG_TEST

C:\zzzztemp>echo .\BUG_TEST\*.*
.\BUG_TEST\*.*

C:\zzzztemp>del .\BUG_TEST\*.*
C:\zzzztemp\BUG_TEST\*.*, Are you sure (Y/N)? y

C:\zzzztemp>pause
Press any key to continue . . .
```

So far so good, just as expected.

**But**, if I accidentally have a tab at the end of specifying the folder variable

```
set backup_folder=.\BUG_TEST{accidentally had a tab here}
```

Results in:

```
C:\zzzztemp>set backup_folder=.\BUG_TEST

C:\zzzztemp>echo .\BUG_TEST     \*.*
.\BUG_TEST      \*.*

C:\zzzztemp>del .\BUG_TEST      \*.*
C:\zzzztemp\BUG_TEST\*, Are you sure (Y/N)? y
C:\*.*, Are you sure (Y/N)?
```

As you can see from the echo output, this is being interpreted as two arguments to the DEL command, and as a result the DEL operation is being performed **twice**, on two folders, one of which is `c:\*.*`

If one was to run this delete with the /Q (quiet, not requiring prompt to confirm delete), he could wipe out all the files in the root of c: !!!

So, I guess my question comes down to...

**Is there a safe way to write:**

```
del %backup_folder%\*.*
```

**...Such that I would get a runtime error rather than an unintentional execution of delete with two arguments in the event that an unseen tab gets appended onto the variable assignment?**

Comment: This is the usual behaviour. Tabspace is one of the default delimiters in Windows console.

Comment: I tried your batch files. Was most alarmed by the second question confirming deleting all files in the root.

Comment: perhaps this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6700511/replace-tabs-in-a-file-with-semi-colons-using-windows-batch-script

Comment: I suppose it would, but imagine the monstrosity a large batch file would become.  This seems to me like very dangerous unintended behavior.  If doing a diff on a file with ignore whitespace you wouldn't even catch this mistake.

Comment: perhaps make the filter have the delete command in there. So you have to call the filter batch to be able to delete. Otherwise. Create a monitor app which looks for tab files and alerts you. Or get off batch files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
set "backup_folder=.\BUG_TEST" extra chars after last quote are ignored
```

Any characters after the last quote in the above assignment are ignored. No more accidental trailing tabs or spaces in your assignments :-)

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

```
if not "%backup_folder%"=="" if exist "%backup_folder%\*.*" del "%backup_folder%\*.*"
```

Comment: This actually works....when it has no tab appended, it deletes as desired.  When it has a tab appended, it produces an error: "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect."  I'm not quite sure I understand why though, any chance you could explain why this works?

Comment: Enclosing the `del` target in quotes means that the entire content of the quoted item is the target for deletion - it's not a list of items, so an attempt is made to delete `".\bug_test[tabchar]\*.*"` not `.\bug_test` AND `\*.*`. Simply quoting your deltion target may also be a solution....

Comment: I edited my answer so that it will not generate an error in the case that spaces or tabs complicate the path - but Dave's suggestion of enclosing the variable in quotes is the right way to go about it.  You can also eliminate the `.\\` before the directory name and it will protect the root folder from deletion.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
ECHO test 1 - no stray TAB
set backup_folder=.\BUG_TEST
CALL :check %backup_folder%
IF NOT "%fcheck%"=="%backup_folder%" ECHO Suspect foldername +%backup_folder%+&GOTO :EOF 
echo %backup_folder%\*.*
ECHO del %backup_folder%\*.*

ECHO test 2 - deliberate stray TAB

:: generate a TAB character
SET "TAB=   "

ECHO testing tab exists:%tab%:exists IF there's a gap between the colons
ECHO show it is a TAB%tab%:the
ECHO show it  is a TAB%tab%:colons
ECHO show it   is a TAB%tab%:should
ECHO show it    is a TAB%tab%:align


set backup_folder=.\BUG_TEST%tab%
CALL :check %backup_folder%
IF NOT "%fcheck%"=="%backup_folder%" ECHO Suspect foldername +%backup_folder%+&GOTO :EOF 
echo %backup_folder%\*.*
ECHO del %backup_folder%\*.*
GOTO :eof

:check
SET fcheck=%1
GOTO :eof
```

Hmm - don't be alarmed by its size - most is commentary and there are two separate situations tested (with and without `TAB`)

- Not sure whether cut-and-paste will work successfully here - the tab actually must be a `tab` - but OP is good at those - perhaps overly so...
- Note the `set "var=value"` syntax - designed to stop um - stray invisible characters at the end of lines being included in the value assigned...

The `:check` routine uses the separators [space][tab][;][,][=] to assign a value - if the value assigned is identical to the original, then there were no separators.